# Spring security form action login is not working

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security, custom-authentication

I am trying to authenticate with spring security with form login.

I am using custom authentication. It was working perfectly when my system has Java 1.8. Recently I have upgraded Java 1.8 to 1.10, Then onwards form is not submitting. I am getting below error.

```
 This www.act.com page can’t be found
 No webpage was found for the web address: www.act.com/appname/login
 HTTP ERROR 404
```

Below is my login form.

```
    <form class="smart-form client-form"  name ="login" id="login-form" 
                        accept-charset="UTF-8"  role="form" method="post">
                        <header> Log In </header>

                        <fieldset>
                            <section> <label class="label">User Name</label> <label
                                class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i> <input
                                type="text" name="username" id="uname"/> <b
                                class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i
                                    class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i> Please enter username</b></label> </section>

                            <section> <label class="label">Password</label> <label
                                class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i> <input
                                type="password" name="password" id="pw" /> <b
                                class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i
                                    class="fa fa-lock txt-color-teal"></i> Enter your password</b>
                            </label>

                            </section>
                             <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

                        </fieldset>
                        <footer>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign in</button>
```

I am appending action while submitting the form in jquery.

```
  $('#login-form').attr('action',"login");
```

Any one have suggestions. It would be appreciated for your help.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you response. It's there as hidden parameter. The same code is working with java 8.

Comment: You mean I have to send JSESSIONID manually.

Comment: Are you sure your server running without any error?

Comment: Yes server is running and added  input type hidden with name of JSESSIONID 
 and values is <%= session.getId()> still i am getting same error mentioned above.

Comment: Please check your configuration.The login url  should be `permitAll` and turn off the `csrf` temporarily

Comment: Hi It is saying that 404 webpage not found, My URL pattern is /pages/*. but my action simply login from the beginning It was working. Any way I tried disabling csrf and given permitAll for /login. What can place in action now it is "login"

Comment: Please include your configuration classes. I couldn't guess more.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, Actually default action of form login spring security is login that's how our code was. Do you have any idea about what action i have to give in for while submitting it to spring security custom authentication.

Comment: set `loginProcessingUrl` if you are using java based.

Comment: Hey thnks for you vision. Found the problem there is exception in encryption algorithm while logging. Thanks for your effort.